# How to show $\sum_{i=0}^{2m} (-1)^{i}\binom{2m}{i}^{2} = (-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

I am trying to show that for any positive integer m, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2m} (-1)^{i}\binom{2m}{i}^{2} = (-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}$$

Intuitively this seems to be true, $m = 0$ both sides evaluate to $1$, $m = 1$ both sides evaluate to $-2$.

I was looking at this identity for a potential connection, but it seems not applicable here $$\binom{2n}{n} = \binom{n}{0}^{2} + \binom{n}{1}^{2} + \binom{n}{2}^{2} + ... + \binom{n}{n}^{2}$$

Also I was trying to find connections between this and the binomial theorem, but no luck

Comment: I don't think so, I see the similarity, but it doesn't help me with my question. Would appreciate an answer to my question

Comment: @DanielWang What is your question?

Comment: Showing that $\sum_{i=0}^{2m} (-1)^{i}\binom{2m}{i}^{2} = (-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}$

Comment: It's exactly the same question, isn't it?  What is the difference?  BTW, the last answer to the linked question is the one to look at -- very simple and elegant.

Comment: The RHS is the same, but the LHS isn't

Comment: oh okay, I see, got it

Answer (score 2):

$(1+x)^{2m} \ =\ {2m \choose 0} + {2m \choose 1}x\ ..........\  {2m \choose 2m}x^{2m}$

$(x-1)^{2m} \ =\ {2m \choose 0}x^{2m}-{2m \choose 1}x^{2m-1}\ .......\ {2m \choose 2m}$

Observe coefficient of $x^{2m}$ in $(1+x)^{2m}(1-x)^{2m}$ is nothing but $\sum_{i=0}^{2m} (-1)^{i}\binom{2m}{i}^{2}$ = $ S $

$S$ = coefficent of $x^{2m}$ in $(1-x^2)^{2m}$ which easily can be seen by binomial theorm = $(-1)^m\binom{2m}{m}$